# iOS CMStepCounter & CMMotionActivityManager

Tags: ios, core-motion, cmmotionmanager, apple-m7

I am using `CMStepCounter` and `CMMotionActivityManager`.

What I would like to do is work out my total walking time throughout the day, and from this, my average speed.

However, looking at the data in `CMMotionActivityManager`, it is clear than a number of steps throughout the day are actually logged during periods that are of 'unknown activity' and not walking or running. This does make sense, as you need to do a handful of steps for iOS to know you are walking. However, these add up over the course of any given day.

Querying `CMMotionActivity`, it is possible to get the timestamp of every event. However, whilst it is clear to me that every step must be timestamped in `CMStepCounter`, I can only see a method to return the total number of steps between two points in time. What would be great is if I could return an array of every step with its time stamp, and if so, how?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current Core Motion API, you can't get an array of every step with its time stamp directly.

But you can use `queryActivityStartingFromDate:toDate:toQueue:withHandler:` to get an array of `CMMotionActivity` objects. Then use the time stamps to calculate the number of steps by calling `queryStepCountStartingFrom:to:toQueue:withHandler:`.

I don't think the M7 processor stores every step with its own time stamp. If you pass `1` as `stepCounts` to the method `startStepCountingUpdatesToQueue:updateOn:withHandler:`, you'll notice the handler is not executed on every step. Like the document says: *The handler block is executed on a best effort basis each time the step count threshold is exceeded.*